# How to send data through HTTPS with python?

Tags: python, https

I would like to know how to send data to a website using `HTTPS` in python.

It seems simple to do it with `HTTP` but I could not manage to find the same for `HTTPS` requests...

Comment: How did you do it with `http`? What have you tried with `https`?

Comment: Are you trying to log in to a specific website?

Comment: I use urllib2 to post with http. I did not tried yet with https convinced that I had to used something like SSL for the server to accept my connection.

Comment: urllib2 supports https directly. As seen in [their examples section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://example.com')
print r.status_code
```

If you want to use [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), here is a snippet taken directly from [their examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> req = urllib2.Request(url='https://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi',
...                       data='This data is passed to stdin of the CGI')
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> print f.read()
Got Data: "This data is passed to stdin of the CGI"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Could you tell if my data will be encrypted ?

Comment: As long as the URL starts with `https://` and the web server is properly configured, the data will be encrypted.